# Before Update Case

Tags: case, before-trigger, insert

Retrieve existing case, do not create a new case.

```java
trigger ValidateCase on Case (before insert) {
    if(Trigger.isBefore && Trigger.isInsert){
        for(Case newCase : Trigger.new) {
            // Busca caso con mismo número telefónico
            List<Case> existingCases = [SELECT Id
                                        FROM Case
                                        WHERE Status = 'Abierto' AND
                                        RecordType.DeveloperName = 'ClosedFalse' AND
                                        Origin = 'Phone' AND
                                        ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC
                                        LIMIT 1];
            
            // Validated accountcon                  
            List<Account> accounts = [SELECT Id
                                      FROM Account
                                      WHERE PhoneAccount= :newCase.Phone
                                      LIMIT 1];
            
            if(!existingCases.isEmpty() && !accounts.isEmpty()) {
                // Case and Account existing
                Case existingCase = existingCases[0];
                
                newCase.Id = existingCase.Id;
                NewCase.getCase(existingCase.Id);
                //newCase.addError('Existing'+ existingCase.Id);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I need to retrieve the id of an existing case, not create a new case.
Test:

```java
@isTest
public class CreateCaseTalkdeskTest {
    @isTest 
    static void testPreventDuplicateCase() {
        Account testAccount = new Account(RecordType = [SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE DeveloperName = 'PersonAccount'], 
                                          FirstName = 'Test',
                                          LastName = 'Pruebas',
                                          PhoneAccount= '1234567891');
                                      
        insert testAccount;
    
        Case existingCase = new Case(Status='Abierto',
                                     Phone='1234567891');
                                 
        insert existingCase;
     
        Case newCase = new Case(Status='Abierto',
                                Phone='1234567891');
                             
        Test.startTest();
    
        insert newCase;
      
        Test.stopTest();
    
        // Validate case Id
        Case resultCase = [SELECT Id, Phone, Description 
                           FROM Case
                           WHERE Id = :newCase.Id]; 
        System.debug('Existing Case Id: ' + existingCase.Id);
        System.debug('New Case Id: ' + newCase.Id);
        
        System.assertEquals(existingCase.Id, resultCase.Id);
        
        // Validate msj error
        System.assertEquals('Caso existente', resultCase.Description);
    }
}
```

Comment: and what is the problem? Que es el problema?

Comment: FATAL_ERROR System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Expected: 5008G000005zCOjQAM, Actual: 5008G000005zCOkQAM
I don't want to create a new case, I want to show case found

Comment: @Derek F
Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do is impossible. You cannot turn an insert into an update. Instead, you'll want to learn about the [upsert](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_dml_examples_upsert.htm) DML operation. This allows you to create or update a case based on a field. You'll have to arrange for an [External ID](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.faq_import_general_what_is_an_external.htm&type=5) that can be used, and you'll have to combine the data somehow so that these values are unique.

Comment: I want to recover an existing case, to later show a message with the case ID, if one exists, open this message and if not, continue with the creation of the case.

Comment: @Desaarolladorx That's not what your unit test is trying to do, nor the code you wrote to begin with. You'll want to just use addError if that is your intent.

Answer (score 0):

What fields on Case do you use to see if it's unique in order to check if it already exists. Your WHERE clause is only saying Status = 'Abierto' AND RecordType.DeveloperName = 'ClosedFalse' AND Origin = 'Phone'. You need a unique identifier if you want to be able to tell if the case already exists.

Also you shouldn't do queries or DML in loops. You should query for all existing cases first and then loop over the records in the trigger context.

Comment: Thanks for reading, I do my validation with:
`code`

      List<Case> existingCases = [SELECT Id, Phone FROM Case WHERE Status = 'Abierto' 
       AND RecordType.DeveloperName = 'ClosedFalse' AND Origin = 'Phone' AND  Phone= 
         :newCase.Phone ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC  LIMIT 1];

I validate that the phone number that appears in the Phone field is equal to the PhoneAccount account field